# MVC: Other partial views lost after a post to a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, partial-views

I have a partial view where I do a submit:

```
<input type="image" src="~/Resources/Images/DoSomething.png" border="0" alt="Submit" value="DoSomething" name="DoSomething"/>
```

The controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel myModel)
{
    DoSomethingToManipulateTheModel(myModel);

    return PartialView("~/Views/MyPartialView.cshtml", myModel);
}
```

In the function DoSomething() I want to manipulate myModel and send it back to the view.

But I have a problem:
After calling DoSomething, only the partial view is shown and without styling. 
How can I update a partialview without losing the other partial views and styling?

Comment: Unless this is happening via some AJAX construct, you're essentially loading a new page which contains only the partial view being returned by the server.  Either return an entire page or use AJAX in some way to update only part of the in-browser page rather than doing a form post.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `$.ajax`, add `onclick="someJsFunction()"` to your button and in

```
someJsFunction(e)
{
e.preventDefault();

//do the ajax hit here to your action method
//and on the success event of ajax append the partial view html to the //corresponding div where you want to show the partial content

//and don't forget to set the datatype:html in ajax parameters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below code for return result of partial view

```html
<input type="image" src="~/Resources/Images/DoSomething.png" border="0" id="SubmitBtn" alt="Submit" value="DoSomething" name="DoSomething"/>
```

You have to add "**PartialResultDivName**" Div on your view and show return data in that div. check below code for that.

```js
 $("#SubmitBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax(
                   {
                       url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "ControllerName")',
                       type: "Post",
                       async: false,
                        dataType: "html",
                       contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                       data: $('form').serialize(), //here you have to pass your form name for pass all data to controller action
                     contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                       success: function (data) {
                            $('#PartialResultDivName').html(data);
                       }
                   });
 });
```

Comment: You said:"You have to add "PartialResultDivName" Div on your view". I don't know where to put it. I replaced PartialResultDivName with the id of my main div but this does not work

Comment: <div id="PartialResultDivName"></div> its id of div for showing return result. on that view where you have added <input type="image"> button on that main view.

Comment: Then I did what you suggested. But the result is the same. Only the partial view is shown

Comment: The result should be  Main view with Partial view when you add above code.